# When the window resizes then the button should work differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width < '700') 
{
    $(".fevent").removeAttr('data-toggle data-target aria-expanded aria-controls');
    $(".fevent").attr({"data-toggle":"collapse", "data-target":"#bol", "aria-expanded":"false", "aria-controls":"bol"});
    $(".fevent").on("click",function(){
    $("#bol").collapse('toggle');
    });
} else if ($(window).width > '700') 
{
    $(".fevent").removeAttr('data-toggle data-target aria-expanded aria-controls');
    $(".fevent").attr({"data-toggle":"collapse", "data-target":"#col", "aria-expanded":"false", "aria-controls":"col"});
    $(".fevent").on("click", function(){
    $("#col").collapse('toggle');
    });
}
});
```

.fvent is the class of button , when i resize my window then the button should function differently,
when the window is less than the 700 then clicking on button show div id #bol otherwise #col .

The button is working for width > 700 when i resizes the window less than 700 it still works as the width > 700.

PLEASE HELP ME OUT!!!

Comment: Because the previous `.on()` event listener is still active, maybe. See: https://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: @Deykun look carefully, the on click event triggers a different selector. But I think you are correct about the resize listener.

Comment: Are there actually two elements, `#bol` and `#col`? Seems like some refactoring could dramatically simplify things here. Please post a snippet of your HTML.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't be setting all that stuff manually. Use [collapse methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#methods) instead.

Comment: @isherwood #bol and #col are different divs one for mobile and one for desktop respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to use any additional JavaScript for this. Just use 2 buttons and show and hide them with media queries:

```css
.btn.col {
  display:none;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .btn.col {
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .btn.bol {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary bol" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bol" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="bol">Toggle bol</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary col" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="col">Toggle col</button>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse" id="col">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis enim ornare, ullamcorper ipsum ut, bibendum mi. Quisque sit amet velit dignissim, tincidunt neque nec, consequat dolor.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="collapse" id="bol">
      <div class="card card-body">
        Vivamus auctor commodo nisl ut vestibulum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam eu leo non nunc ullamcorper fermentum. Donec vehicula dolor sed augue maximus, non congue urna semper.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$(document).ready()` is trigged only once so you are checking viewport width only on document load.

You have to add `$(window).on('resize')` function and check viewport the size there.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` is triggered only the page loads; it's not triggered when the page is resized.

You can try  `$(window).on('resize',function(){ ...`